# How to align a long math line without centering text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

This is not an equation, it's just a long math line. I want to break it into lines with right alignment. I tried several solutions including `align`, `multline`, but somehow I can't get it to work properly. It always forces the text to center. If I use `equation` + `split`, it still force the text center. Is there a way to get rid of the centering property? Thank you.

Minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\begin{document}
    $X \times Y = \{$
            $\{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{a, e\}, \{a, f\},$ \\
            $\{b, b\}, \{b, c\}, \{b, e\}, \{b, f\},$ \\
            $\{c, b\}, \{c, c\}, \{c, e\}, \{c, f\},$ \\
            $\{d, b\}, \{d, c\}, \{d, e\}, \{d, f\} \}$ 
\end{document}
```

**Edit** (according to Stefan Kottwitz's solution)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could insert

```
\hspace*{\fill}
```

at the left of the lines with inline math to get right aligned inline math formulas.

Or use `flalign*`, such as

```
\begin{flalign*}
  X \times Y = \{&\\
  && \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{a, e\}, \{a, f\}, \\
  && \{b, b\}, \{b, c\}, \{b, e\}, \{b, f\}, \\
  && \{c, b\}, \{c, c\}, \{c, e\}, \{c, f\}, \\
  && \{d, b\}, \{d, c\}, \{d, e\}, \{d, f\} \}
\end{flalign*}
```

Alternative, aligned at brace and all moved to the left:

```
\noindent Text
\begin{flalign*}
 X \times Y = \{&\{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{a, e\}, \{a, f\}, &\\
& \{b, b\}, \{b, c\}, \{b, e\}, \{b, f\}, &\\
& \{c, b\}, \{c, c\}, \{c, e\}, \{c, f\}, &\\
& \{d, b\}, \{d, c\}, \{d, e\}, \{d, f\} \}
\end{flalign*}
```

[image: flalign example]

Comment: Wow, you're quick. Thanks a lot ;). I tried your `flalign*` example, however, it makes the text align to the right, not left though :(. Is there a way to align make it align with the `\{` above it?

Comment: @Chan: another example added

Comment: Thanks again ;). By the way, if the line `X times Y` is actually the subsection title. I wonder if they could be in the same line? because the `\begin` and `\end` force a line break. How can I prevent this to happen? See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
     \usepackage{mathtools}          
\begin{document}     
\begin{multline}             
X \times Y = \{ \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{a, e\}, \{a, f\}, \\                 
\shoveright{\{b, b\}, \{b, c\}, \{b, e\}, \{b, f\},} \\                 
\shoveright{\{c, b\}, \{c, c\}, \{c, e\}, \{c, f\},} \\                 
\{d, b\}, \{d, c\}, \{d, e\}, \{d, f\} \}      
\end{multline}      

\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
        X \times Y = \{
        &    \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{a, e\}, \{a, f\}, \\
        &    \{b, b\}, \{b, c\}, \{b, e\}, \{b, f\}, \\
        &    \{c, b\}, \{c, c\}, \{c, e\}, \{c, f\}, \\
        &    \{d, b\}, \{d, c\}, \{d, e\}, \{d, f\} \} 
\end{split}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, from the 2nd line up to end, they align in the middle not right to the `\{`. Any other idea?

Comment: @Chan: do you mean something like the edited answer?

Comment: Yes, that almost is. However, I want the part `X \times Y` not centering though. Is there a way to force `X \times Y` to the left, and the rest move accordingly? Thanks again.

Comment: @Chan: see edit

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately, it gave the same result, the first line is still centered.